# Displaying current date with momentjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

This is the div where I want to display current date.

```
<div id="date">
    <!--Displaying Date-->
</div>
```

This is the script I am using to display date.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     $("#date").val( moment().format('ddd MMM Do, YYYY') );

});
```

What I want is to display a date inside my div but it is displaying nothing. Could anyone figure out what am I doing wrong ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

#date is not an input, you cannot set val().
Use text() or html() instead:

```
     $("#date").text(moment().format('ddd MMM Do, YYYY'));
```

## Edit

Here is a [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/derrwbev/) of your code

If you cannot achieve the same result please check one of following:

1. There are any hints (errors) in your browser console?
2. Momentjs and jQuery files are successfully loaded when you methods in the snippet?

Comment: Great example that you have given here and working well as I changed it to ".text(moment()".  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

`val()` is used for textarea or input tag

For div tag `text()` is used write `text()` instead of `val()`
i.e. $('#date').text(..);

Comment: Thanks for your pointing my mistake and it has done great job.